# Can I send controller inputs to two devices?

Tags: nintendo-switch

I want to have something that lets me use my Switch Pro Controller on my computer while simultaneously controlling my switch at the same time. I want to kind of use my pc as an input viewer (I'll worry about the drivers later), and I can't figure out a good way to do it. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: I know its definitely possible, plenty of switch streamers show their controller input on their streams at the same time.

Comment: If you mean for N64/GameCube, that’s an Arduino. I have one and it works, but I need I for usb. Also there is a switch pro input viewer that uses a board that costs about as much as the island of *insert island name*, so that’s out of question